# How can I update more than one record in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
Select Stackoverflow.* From Stackoverflow Where GeneralId = 1000;
```

The above sql returns 3 records like:

```
Id     GeneralId    Name             StateId
1       1000        stack             null
2       1000        stackover         null
3       1000        stackoverflow     null
```

I want to update StateId of returned records.

On the other hand

It is possible sometimes the count of record can be 1, sometimes 3 like above example.

```
Select Stackoverflow.* From Stackoverflow Where GeneralId = 1001;
```

Above sql statement returns only one record.

```
Id     GeneralId    Name        StateId
8       1001        stck         null
```

So how can I update these returned record.
I think there should be a loop from 0 to the count of record and in that loop

I only try to write Pseudocode.

```
Update    Stackoverflow
Set StateId = 1
where = "loop as I mentioned should be come?"
```

Isn't it? Any idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one would be:

```
UPDATE Stackoverflow
Set StateId = 1
where GeneralId = 1000;
```

For the second one:

```
UPDATE Stackoverflow
Set StateId = 1
where GeneralId = 1001;
```

For both of them:

```
UPDATE Stackoverflow
Set StateId = 1
where GeneralId IN (1000,1001);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try

```
Update    Stackoverflow
Set StateId = 1
where GeneralId = 1000;
```

It will update all records corresponding to the WHERE clause, should they be 1 or 1000.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set all records selected by the WHERE clause to the same value you just write

```
Update Stackoverflow Set StateId = 1 WHERE GeneralID = 1000
```

and all three records (or the only one when GeneralID = 1001) will be updated with the new value
The UPDATE statement works on the set of records retrieved by the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
Update    Stackoverflow
Set StateId = 1
where Id in (
//Your query if you want to customize
Select Id From Stackoverflow Where GeneralId = 1001;
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using SQL Server's `update ... from` syntax, like:

```
update  tbl1
set     stateid = 1
from    ... your query here ...
```

For example:

```
update  tbl1
set     stateid = 1
from    Stackoverflow as tbl1
where   tbl1.GeneralId = 1000
```